# Converting accelerate's A array representation to repa's U array representation

Tags: haskell, repa, accelerate-haskell

I'd like to convert an accelerate array to a repa array, before then using `writeImageToBMP` from repa-io to write the array to a BMP file. Ignore the fact that there exists such a function in accelerate-io, I'm just using it as an example of the question. Take:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import qualified Data.Array.Accelerate.Interpreter as A (run)
import Data.Array.Accelerate
import qualified Data.Array.Accelerate as A
import qualified Data.Array.Accelerate.IO as A
import qualified Data.Array.Repa as Repa
import qualified Data.Array.Repa.IO.BMP as Repa
import GHC.Word

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let accelArr = A.fromList
                 (Z :. (2::Int) :. (1::Int))
                 ([(1,2,3),(4,5,6)] :: [(Word8,Word8,Word8)])
      computation :: A.Acc (A.Array A.DIM2 (Word8,Word8,Word8))
      computation = A.map
       (\triple ->
           let (r',g',b') = unlift triple :: (Exp Word8,Exp Word8,Exp Word8)
           in lift (constant 0,g',b')) (use accelArr)
      repaArr :: Repa.Array A.A Repa.DIM2 (Word8,Word8,Word8)
      repaArr = A.toRepa (A.run computation)
  Repa.writeImageToBMP "out_repa.bmp" repaArr
```

The packages accelerate, accelerate-io, repa and repa-io are reuired to compile this code.

This doesn't compile because the type for `writeImageToBmp` in repa-io is:

```
writeImageToBMP
  :: FilePath
  -> Repa.Array Repa.U Repa.DIM2 (Word8, Word8, Word8)
  -> IO ()
```

Where `U` represents a manifest array in repa. The GHC error is:

```
Couldn't match type ‘A.A’ with ‘Repa.U’
Expected type: Repa.Array Repa.U Repa.DIM2 (Word8, Word8, Word8)
  Actual type: Repa.Array A.A Repa.DIM2 (Word8, Word8, Word8)
In the second argument of ‘Repa.writeImageToBMP’, namely ‘repaArr’
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  Repa.writeImageToBMP "out_repa.bmp" repaArr
```

The type of `repaArr` is:

```
Repa.Array A.A Repa.DIM2 (Word8,Word8,Word8)
```

Which is why GHC is complaining about it being an argument to `writeImageToBMP`.

**Question:** How do I convert the accelerate array representation `A` to the repa manifest array representation `U`, so that I can call `writeImageToBMP` on it?

Comment: The same way you convert any Repa array to an unboxed Repa array: [`computeUnboxed{S/P}`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-3.2.3.3/docs/Data-Array-Repa.html#v:computeUnboxedP).

Comment: @user2407038 - I was able to get `copyP` and `copyS` to work, but not any of the compute methods due to a missing `Load` constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the functions **computeS**, **computeP**, **copyS** and **copyP** in [Data.Array.Repa](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa-3.4.0.1/docs/Data-Array-Repa.html#v:computeP) have this kind of signature:

```
...constraints... => Array r1 sh e -> m (Array r2 sh e)
```

and therefore they are functions which allow you to convert between different Repa representations (i.e. convert r1 -> r2).

With that in mind I got this code to type check:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let accelArr = A.fromList
                 (Z :. (2::Int) :. (1::Int))
                 ([(1,2,3),(4,5,6)] :: [(Word8,Word8,Word8)])
      computation :: A.Acc (A.Array A.DIM2 (Word8,Word8,Word8))
      computation = A.map
       (\triple ->
           let (r',g',b') = unlift triple :: (Exp Word8,Exp Word8,Exp Word8)
           in lift (constant 0,g',b')) (use accelArr)
      repaArr :: Repa.Array A.A Repa.DIM2 (Word8,Word8,Word8)
      repaArr = A.toRepa (A.run computation)
  zzz <- Repa.copyP repaArr
  Repa.writeImageToBMP "out_repa.bmp" zzz
```

You can also use `Repa.copyS` here.